# Retrieving OAuth 2.0 Access and Refresh Tokens for Fusion Tables via Python

Tags: oauth-2.0, python-2.7, google-fusion-tables

I am attempting to retrieve both access and refresh tokens for an application to access a fusion table of mine.  I am using the OAuth 2.0 method and simply need to allow users who visit my application to INSERT records into my fusion table.

The problem I am encountering is when running the [python script](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/oauth_tokens.py) described by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables).  The error I receive when running the code out of the box (in PyDev, with Python 2.7 interpreter) is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\..\OAuthToken\root\oauth_tokens.py", line 59, in <module>
    redirect_uri)
  File "\\..\OAuthToken\root\oauth_tokens.py", line 41, in retrieve_tokens
    refresh_token = tokens['refresh_token']
KeyError: 'refresh_token'
```

Does anybody have a solution for me?  I read somewhere on GitHub ( github.com/ff0000/red-social-auth/issues/3 - I'm not allowed to post anymore links) something to do with refresh_tokens being semi-retired, but clearly I'm just grasping at straws at this point.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was having the same issue as stated in the original question and was coming up with nothing.  But then I found [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl), specifying that the original request needed to have `access_type=offline` so that a refresh token was sent.  So I added that to Kathryn's [oauth_tokens script](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/oauth_tokens.py) like so.

Edited line 17:

```
  print '%s?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s&access_type=offline&response_type=code' % \
```

Well I thought this would solve my problem but it did not.  I guess since the application initially registered with the default access type of "online" it would not grant a refresh token.  This was solved by revoking access to the application under the Google account settings page.

Accounts -> Security -> Authorizing applications and sites -> Edit

I hope this helps someone as this was driving me nuts for a while.

I have added the script I am using on Github: https://github.com/mejackreed/fusion-tables-oauth-tokens/blob/master/oauth.py

Comment: Hi, I've been thrashing at this for awhile, with limited success.  I've edited line 17 as above, and at first things worked fine: I was getting back Access and Refresh Tokens.  But alas, today I try the same exact steps, and start getting the same errors as before...and yes, I've tried it with taking out the 'access_type=offline', and with 'revoking' access, and attempting to redo secret keys, and toggling the API console access for Fusion Tables on-off, etc., but at this point I can no longer get the python script to work...any ideas why it might work fine one day, and then not the next?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what is going on with your script but I just checked mine and it still works fine.